# SQLite.Interop.dll missing after publishing a Windows Forms .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite

Project was able to run without any error. After publishing and installing it, i get the following error.

"Unable to load DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"

I checked the reference Tree and the property "Copy Local" for the Sqlite data provider is set to "True". What else should i check?

Comment: *'After publishing and installing it...'* → How do you publish and install it?

Comment: If you are using ClickOnce publishing, then you may find this post useful: [Click once not installing some files to users machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65738299/3110834)

Comment: i use the ClickOnce. Actually, my previous attempt on another project was successful. Also, some pictures are not uploaded, but this must be due interruption from the dll error. Pictures are contained on resources folder.
I have installed Stub.System.Data.SQLite.Core.NetFramework  and System.Data.SQLite.Core packages. I believe that the error is related on those packages

Answer (score -1):

You need to check:

- File path
- Installed/Uninstalled programs (conflict)
- Dll version

Comment: Seems that i am missing something important, since neither the media resources are available (some pictures)